# How to get a list of all installed applications in client's computer?

Tags: javascript, html, windows, ubuntu, web

I want to know the html code which can list all applications installed in client's PC ?? Does any one know the way ?? Thanks for response in advance.

Comment: Plugins are possible, though: `navigator.plugins`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript Run time Engine not have **Permission** to access System information.You must use java applet to run command in user client.

Comment: Can you share that java applet which serves the purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer, there is no html code that can do this as HTML is markup.
Likewise Javascript running in a browser will not have permissions to access this sort of information.